# "Bad Request" when trying to view question linked from main page

Tags: bug, status-completed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677241/is-fn-ogn-%D3%A8gn-or-%EF%81%97gn) was just posted on the main page, but trying to view it gives an HTTP 400 "Bad Request" page. I can't seem to view it by cutting off the last part of the URL, which I expect is the problem.

What can I do to view the question?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a repro locally; I'll working on it, to prevent this being a problem in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed next deployment; I have added exclusions on the unicode private use areas and "other not assigned" areas (to a range of other pre-existing exclusions etc), so that we don't attempt to use them in URLs.